# Unrecognized parameter to $filter: limit MongoDB-Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following error on my console:: *Invalid $project :: caused by :: Unrecognized parameter to $filter: limit*

The irony of this is that the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.3/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) tells us that it exists and can be used.

**This is my code**

```
const docWorker = await _worker.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        credencial: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: [{ $size: "$identificacionObra" }, 0],
            },
            then: false,
            else: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $gte: [
                    {
                      $size: {
                        $filter: {
                          input: "$identificacionObra",
                          cond: {
                            $eq: ["$$credencial.estado", true],
                          },
                          as: "credencial",
                          limit: 1,  <--------- the limit parameter does not work
                        },
                      },
                    },
                    1,
                  ],
                },
                then: true,
                else: false,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    { $match: _match },
    { $sort: _sort },
    {
      $facet: {
        paginatedResults: [
          { $skip: req.query.page * req.query.limit - req.query.limit },
          { $limit: parseInt(req.query.limit) },
        ],
        totalCount: [
          {
            $count: "count",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ]);
```

Please help me, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Read the documentation carefully: MongoDB Manual 5.3 **(upcoming)** - Current release is 5.0, you need to wait a few weeks.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit -.- I really didn't realize, what a shame, thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Check the version of MongoDb, limit in filter is only avaible in 6.0

here's documentation of 5.0 https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33940337)